# makeForkCluster workers hanging

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I'm having issues with parallel workers hanging when I call

```
myCluster <- makeForkCluster(slots, outfile="outfile.log")
```

This issue occurs intermittently and it's difficult to reproduce, but when it does happen I get this in outfile.log:

```
starting worker pid=39158 on localhost:11767 at 08:19:48.716
Error in socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE,  

cannot open the connection

Calls: makeForkCluster -> newForkNode -> socketConnection
```

If I look up the pid in htop, I see it's doing absolutely nothing, just sitting there. How can I diagnose this?

Comment: The issue is that even though outfile.log may report an error, the main program does not go into error state, so the only way I find out that the worker couldn't connect, is if I check that log. Ideally the main program would go into error state as soon as the worker can't connect.

Comment: Because that is a hack. This is a shared corporate codebase. It is better to find an actual solution to the problem rather than a workaround.

Comment: You're being presumptuous. I'm a woman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169252/discussion-between-user3055163-and-rinspy).